# Formatting text outputs in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, text-processing

Hi I have a list here:

**list_1.txt**

```
Alpha

Bravo

Charlie
```

and files in a directory with the following filenames and contents:

**Alpha_123.log**

```
This is a sample line in the file
error_log "This is error1 in file"
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
error_log "This is error2 in file"
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
error_log "This is error3 in file"
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
```

**Alpha_123.sh**

```
This is a sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
error_log "This is errorA in file"
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
error_log "This is errorB in file"
This is another sample line in the file
This is another sample line in the file
error_log "This is errorC in file"
This is another sample line in the file
```

**Bravo.log**

**Charlie.log**

contents of Bravo.log and Charlie.log is similar to Alpha.log

I would like to have an output like this:

```
Alpha|"This is error1 in file"

Alpha|"This is error2 in file"

Alpha|"This is error3 in file"

Alpha|"This is errorA in file"

Alpha|"This is errorB in file"

Alpha|"This is errorC in file"
```

Any inputs is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

So basically, I would like to find first the files with names containing the string patterns in list_1.txt, then find the error messages and output with |

Comment: you could start with formatting the question - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and add what you've tried to solve this problem..

Comment: your question is unclear. Update your description

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: Basically, I want to find the log files with the string patterns in list_1.txt. Then search those files  for lines containing "error_log" and have an output that contains the string pattern in list_1.txt and the lines containing the "error_log" separated by pipe.

Comment: I have this but this:
cat list_1.txt | awk '{print $1}' | while read x ; do echo $x"|" `ls log_directory | grep $x | xargs -i grep error_log log_directory {} | egrep -v` ; done 

But the output is like this:
Alpha|error_log "This is error1 in file" error_log "This is error2 in file" error_log "This is error3 in file"

what I want is this:
Alpha|"This is error1 in file"
Alpha|"This is error2 in file"
Alpha|"This is error3 in file"

Comment: @peon: From what I understand, all you need to add to your pipeline would be `| sed 's/[|]error_log[ ]/|/g'` to replace all occurences of `|error_log ` by just `|`. But I do not really follow your approach as it chains many things in a nested way. I tried to suggest an `awk`-only solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284012/2451238). If it doesn't solve your problem, feel free to comment and I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: It didn't clarify. What is "Alpha_123.sh" doing there?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should do:

```sh
 awk -vOFS=\| 'FNR==1{file=FILENAME;sub("[.]log$","",file)}{sub("^error_log ","");print file,$0}' *.log
```

---

**explanation:**

- `-vOFS=\|` sets the *output field separator* to `|`. (The `\` is needed to escape the `|` from the shell (which would treat it as pipe). You could use `-vOFS='|'` instead.)
- `FNR==1{`...`}` makes sure this code is run only once per input file: `FNR` is number of *records* (i.e lines) read by `awk` so far from the current file. So this is only equal to `1` when processing the very first line of each file.
- `file=FILENAME` just stores the filename of the currently processed input file in a variable for later editing.
- `sub("[.]log$","",file)` removes `.log` (the `[`...`]` escape the dot (`.`) from being interpreted as *any character* in the regular expression. You could use `\\.` instead.) from the end (that's what the `$` stands for) of the filename.
- `{`...`}` runs the code for every *record*/line of each input file.
- `sub("^error_log ","")` removes `"error_log "` (note the trailing space!) from the beginning (that's what the `^` stands for) of each line ("*record*") of the input.
- `print file,$0` prints the remainder of each *record* (i.e. line) prefixed by the corresponding filenames. Note that the comma (`,`) will be replaced by the *output field separator* specified earlier. You could use `print file "|" $0` instead without specifying the `OFS`.
- `*.log` will make every file ending in `.log` in the current directory an input file for the `awk` command. You could specify `Alpha.log Bravo.log Charly.log` explicitely instead.

---

Here is an alternative using your `list.txt` to construct the filenames:

```sh
awk -vOFS=\| '{file=$0;logfile=file ".log";while(getline < logfile){sub("^error_log ","");print file,$0}}' list.txt
```

---

**explanation**:

- `file=$0` saves the current line (*record*) from `list.txt` in a variable.
- `logfile=file ".log"` appends `.log` to it to get the corresponding log filename.
- `while(getline < logfile){`...`}` will run the code for each line/*record* in the current log file.

The rest should be clear from the above example.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '{gsub(/^error_log /,FILENAME"|")}1' $(awk '{print $0".log"}' list_1.txt)
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the updated info, I think that's what you're looking for.

```
awk '/^error_log/ {split(FILENAME,f,"_"); 
                   gsub(/^error_log /,f[1]"|")}' $(awk '{print $0"_*"}' list_1.txt)
```

Comment: Hi @karaka, thank you for the input. Unfortunately, that does not take into account that finding of the log files using the strings in the list_1.txt

Comment: Did you try? It does what you asked.

Comment: Hi Karaka, sorry I missed some details to my problem, please see updated question.